# Windows Server 2008 Server in VM, in domain: Can not print, access denied

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, printing, rds

I'm having an issue with printing from a particular application from our Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit with licensed Remote Desktop Services (running in Amazon EC2).

When I connect via Remote Desktop Connection, log into the application as a Active Directory user (domain controller on another server) and I try to print to any selected printer, I get "You do not have permission to use the selected printer. If you need access, contact your network administrator."

Following several articles, I tried changing permissions on %WINDIR%\System32\Spool for my Domain Group but I can't because I get "An error occurred while applying security information to: *file/folder* Access is denied

Even if I log into the Server as a Local Administrator, I can not add give full permission to the Domain Group on this folder.

How do I give my Domain Group Full permission recursively to %WINDIR%\System32\Spool ?